# Cannot step into WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have a WCF service running in my local IIS and a separate web solution that I use to make calls to the various endpoints in the service application. Both applications were built using .NET 4 in Visual Studio 2010. This is a somewhat mature project though it is still under constant development.

My development machine was replaced and I am now using Visual Studio 2013 as my dev platform but for some reason I am unable to step into my service from the web app when debugging. The message I get from VS when I attempt to step into the service code is:

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Unable to determine a stopping location. 
>   Verify symbols are loaded. Error while processing breakpoint.

I have a VM set up with VS 2010 installed and I can step into the up to date code in the virtual environment. I have set up IIS to use tcp.net on port 808 and net.tcp has been added to the enabled protocols for the service under the Default Web Site. I am using the ASP.NET V4.0 application pool.

The Visual Studio icon associated with the web solution remains the VS2010 but the service solution icon is the new VS2013 icon.

Other than being unable to step through the code from the web app to the service app both projects are working as expected.

I have also tried running the service from Visual Studio and then attaching to that process when debugging the web solution but I still get the same error message even though I was able to attach to the process without errors.

Any help, or pointers are greatly appreciated.