# VS2015:Failed to debug a WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, debugging

I want to debug my `WCF` service hosted with my `WCFClient` application in the same dev box. I can run my WCFClient application successfully. My WCF service binary model is Debug. WCFClient application and WCF service are compiled under `.Net4.5` framework within `windows8 OS`. And my WCF service hosts in IIS7 in the same box as well.

The error is :
Unable to automatically step into the server. Unable to determine a stopping location. Verify symbols are loaded. Error while processing breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Anyone who enters here. I resolved the issue with a console application by invoking my WCF service, this is a bit tricky.

I run my WCF application in asp.net web form. So there will be issue after attaching w3wp.exe process. Then I tried to use a console application to test 
my WCF service, I can debug into the code.

Thanks anyway. I am new to the stackoverflow. Who can help me to know how to close my question?

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: To answer your own question, you need to wait a few hours in order to make your answer "the good one". Add any details (both in the question and the answer) that can help others to solve a similar problem. Keep in mind that SO is a Q&A wiki.

Comment: And remember that a similar question was asked on SO (see the link in my answer). You can contribute by answering it or marking it as duplicate of yours (you may not have sufficient privileges to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you type [an error message in Google](https://www.google.com/?q=unable%20to%20automatically%20step%20into%20the%20server%20unable%20to%20determine%20a%20stopping%20location%20verify%20symbols%20are%20loaded%20error%20while%20processing%20breakpoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=4SRYVp3jK4OtU5vWpMgM#safe=off&q=%22unable%20to%20automatically%20step%20into%20the%20server%20unable%20to%20determine%20a%20stopping%20location%20verify%20symbols%20are%20loaded%20error%20while%20processing%20breakpoint%22), you find your answer... It's typically faster than asking a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249564/cannot-step-into-wcf-service) on SO.

It's also a good idea to write the error message in plain text instead (or in addition to) a screenshot. This way, a person having the same problem will easilly find your question and eventually an answer.

Take a look at [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1232814.aspx) and [this one](http://forums.asp.net/t/2006163.aspx).

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your reply. I did all steps in your suggested links. The issue still happens. I tried to search the existing questions, can't resolve my issue. Any idea then? Thanks.